# How it is done: the picture outside the window

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

On the website http://coder-oldboy.com/ in the first section there is a picture of a window, and outside the window there is a picture of the city. I understand that the elements are arranged using z-index. But the question is, how is the hidden image of the city outside the window? In css, I don't see any rules that would do this.

Comment: Play around with position: fixed

Comment: background of the city on the parent, background of the window on the child simple as that, [code extracted](https://jsfiddle.net/0zveb4oa/)